# django conditional url verify_exists

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 url fields defined in my model as follows:

```
image_1 = models.URLField(max_length=100, verify_exists=True, blank=True)
image_2 = models.URLField(max_length=100, verify_exists=True, blank=True)
image_3 = models.URLField(max_length=100, verify_exists=True, blank=True)
```

My question is, is there a way I can test whether the `verify_exists` returns `True` or `False` and if so take action depending on the output?

Comment: The following link would help you understand: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/)

Comment: thanks, but the field already comes with a validator, im trying to handle the validation proccess and be able to change values in  the field depending on the output of the validator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What django does is it use's [the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#urlvalidator) `URLValidator` to see if the url is valid or not.
what you could is use the same validations which is present in `django.core`

**EDIT:**
For example lets say you have to validate if django official website with url https://www.djangoproject.com/, exists or not. the code would simply look like this:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


my_url_validator = URLValidator(verify_exists=True) #creates a URLValidator object with verify_exists.
my_url = "https://www.djangoproject.com/" #url to be verified   

#check if url is valid :)
try:                           
   my_url_validator(my_url) 
except ValidationError:
   #not valid!! :_( 
   #fix: custom stuff to the rescue :)     
   CustomStuff()...
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by using the same validations in django.core , thanks for reply :)

Comment: i've explained in a bit detail hope that helps

Comment: since django 1.5, verify_exists argument has been deprecated/removed, you can no longer verify for a url existence, its now just a simple regex match for a valid url